# Why can't I "INSERT INTO" my table through my php script?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two different directories on my wampserver, this code works on one, but not on the other, I don't understand why.

PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

$msg = "";
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    header('Location: login.php');
    die();

}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $className = $_POST['className'];
        $classColour = $_POST['classColour'];

        include_once("connection.php");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO class (className, classColour) VALUE ('$className', '$classColour')";
        mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

        $msg = "New class '" . $className . "' added.";
    } else {
        $msg = "No class added yet.";
    }


}


?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="add_class.php">
                    <input type="text" name="className" placeholder="Class" />
                    <input type="text" name="classColour" placeholder="Colour" />
                    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn butn-orange"/></div>
                </form>
```

This is in the file "add_class.php" and I've tried many different things, putting single quotes (`) around the table columns in the $sql but still, it won't work. I've tried adjusting the names in the table, which had underscores but now have camelCasing, still made no difference. This code works perfectly in another directory, can someone please tell me why this is happening and possibly propose a solution? Thank you in advance.

P.S My connection works because I inserted a new row via phpmyadmin and looped through the database printing every existing "className" and it worked, I just can't insert from the php script.

connection.php

```
<?php

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "main");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: `echo $msg = "New class '" . $className . "' added.";` and what do you see?

Comment: Everytime I click "Add" I see this message where the $className is the name I wrote in the input with name="className"

Comment: Please post the exact message as it is?

Comment: If i write "class-name" and click "Add" I get this message "New class 'Class-name' added."

Comment: From where I see it, `connection.php` is could be the culprit. Is `$dbConnection` placed there? Also check if the query fails, I'm sure it does.

Comment: It doesn't, otherwise the user wouldn't be able to log in, and I stated that my connection works because I can print values from my table if I insert them through phpmyadmin

Comment: in which directory you have connection.php? Does that script work in the directory which has connection.php file?

Comment: The same directory as add_class.php, Yes it does. My connection is working fine, the error is caused somewhere in the code I posted

Comment: @sammourac Can you please add the `connection.php` file in your code? (remove the credentials in it ofcourse)

Comment: Why? It is working fine and I am sure of this... I'll post it, but I highly doubt it will help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asked if you've had assigned the sessions, you replied *I assigned this when the user logs in*. Moving forward from that, let's assume the assigned session as one written below:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "HawqasKaPujaari";

$msg = "";

// this fails, as session is already set.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    header('Location: login.php');
    die();

}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $className = $_POST['className'];
        $classColour = $_POST['classColour'];

        include_once("connection.php");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO class (className, classColour) VALUES ('$className', '$classColour')";
        mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

       echo  $msg = "New class '" . $className . "' added.";
    } else {
        $msg = "No class added yet.";
    }


}


?>

<form method="post" action="">
                    <input type="text" name="className" placeholder="Class" />
                    <input type="text" name="classColour" placeholder="Colour" />
                    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="btn butn-orange"/></div>
                </form>
```

> Note: The only changes I made were to change the `action=""` empty and changed `VALUE` to `VALUES` in your query.

connection.php:

```
<?php

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "main");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

As the above posted code seemed to be correct and was bugging me so I thought of testing it myself by creating the database/tables and it seemed to work properly without any errors. I have posted the relevant pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Note: Make sure you have the `connection.php` file in the same
>   directory as the `add_class.php`.

Comment: I tried inserting into another table with the same code and it worked, im guessing that it might be due to the table now, both tables types are "innoDB"

Comment: @sammourac did you use both the column types as `text` with a given a length and was the `collation` any different? Ps. you can always delete and make a new table if it still seems to bug you and let me know how it goes. cheers `;-)`